# Delphi: dbgrid cell press enter to go next cell

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I am working with ADO components to connect Access database on Delphi 2010. 
I wish , as MS Excel, when pressing ENTER adotable.post and next below cell be will selected.

```
 procedure TForm4.DBGrid1Enter(Sender: TObject);
 begin
 adotable1.Edit;
 adotable1.Post;
 ....{below cell will be selected}
 end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below, which is about as simple as it gets, should do what you want.

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_Return then 
    Key := VK_Down;
end;
```

Btw, this code is to be used instead of, not as well as, the code in your q.

(This answer replaces one I posted earlier that involved manipulating the dataset feeding the grid, and did not work in all cases, like when dgMultiSelect is set true).